# Copy a file to multiple windows machines

Tags: windows, files, copy

How can one copy a file, from his windows computer, to a cluster of multiple windows machine, with one command?

I thought about using psexec, but that also tries to execute the file...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's always to the same targets you might want to consider a batch file using a for loop, which simplifies maintenance somewhat. The source and destination can be either coded in or passed as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I still sometimes find a simple batch file handy. This is an example I use to copy a virtual hard drive to 2 different computers for backup.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %date% %time% > E:\buresult.txt
ECHO Backing up E:\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd to E:\WinXP Dev Backup\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd ...
ECHO Backing up E:\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd to E:\WinXP Dev Backup\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd ... >> E:\buresult.txt
copy "E:\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd" "E:\WinXP Dev Backup\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd" /y >> E:\buresult.txt
ECHO %date% %time% >> E:\buresult.txt
ECHO Backing up E:\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd to R:\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd ...
ECHO Backing up E:\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd to R:\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd ... >> E:\buresult.txt
copy "E:\WinXP Dev Hard Disk.vhd" "\\Ibsserver\Backups\bholeman" /y >> E:\buresult.txt
ECHO %date% %time% >> E:\buresult.txt
ECHO Done
ECHO Done >> E:\buresult.txt
TYPE NUL | CHOICE.COM /N /CY /TY,5 >NUL
START E:\buresult.txt
EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this SuperUser thread: https://superuser.com/questions/32630/parallel-file-copy-from-single-source-to-multiple-targets

In short, try N2NCopy or use the batch script that Revolter mentions in the SU thread.